# Bridge and iptables postrouting

Tags: networking, iptables, bridge

I have a Linux 3.14 PC with three NICs and a bridge between two of the NICs (`eth1` and `eth2`).

### My Question

Why is there no traffic passing through the POSTROUTING rule? FYI, traffic is passing through (forwarded) the bridge just fine. Can someone be kind enough to provide me some pointers to get this working?

```
ifconfig eth1 down
ifconfig eth2 down

ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0

ifconfig eth2 up
ifconfig eth2 0.0.0.0

brctl addbr sm0
brctl addif sm0 eth1
brctl addif sm0 eth2

ifconfig sm0 up

iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -p all  -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:99

iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -p all  -j CLASSIFY --set-class 2:99
```

### Rules

```
o iptables -t mangle -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 38914 packets, 2954K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in    out     source         destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 38210 packets, 2791K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in    out     source         destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in    out     source         destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 38072 packets, 2844K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in    out     source         destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 38072 packets, 2844K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in    out     source         destination
    0     0 CLASSIFY   all  --  *     eth1    0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0      CLASSIFY set 1:99
    0     0 CLASSIFY   all  --  *     eth2    0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0      CLASSIFY set 2:99
```

### sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Setting the values below to 0 or 1 has no effect on the iptables

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ipv6tables=1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ipv4tables=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bridge isn't routing traffic, so there's nothing to go through the `POSTROUTING` rule.

See the netfilter documentation for [bridge-netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) for details and a method to change this configuration (kernel 3.2.0):

```
modprobe bridge    # Enable bridge-netfilter
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

Comment: I have the above statement in the system but still no traffic going through the postrouting rule.   I am sure that traffic is flowing through the bridge as I am accessing and posting this from the machine attached to the eth2 NIC (LAN facing) of the bridge.

Comment: I'm sure you're correct that traffic is flowing through the bridge. What I said was that the bridge isn't _routing_ traffic.